# Prevent Int From Being Subtracted

Tags: java, int, subtraction

Is it possible to prevent an int from being subtracted from? The final keyword wouldn't work here, as I still need to be able to add to it. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you can provide a good example, perhaps we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: What's to stop someone adding a negative number then?

Comment: @sparklyllama please accept one of the answers that were given to you or ask if something is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AddButNoSubtract {

    private int i; // private

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void incrementBy(int j) { // instead of setter
        // add if positive
        if (j > 0) {
            // check for overflow
            if (Integer.MAX_VALUE - j >= i)
                this.i += j;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @sparklyllama Glad to help. +1 to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) wrapper class instead of int as Integer class is immutable.

Another idea:

Do not expose your string as a public variable, simply provide method(s) to modify that int. And if someone tries to subtract that string then you can control that within your method.

Answer (score 1):

even if you just disable the subtract then users can still add a negative number... and thus bypass your defense. a wrapper is the only thing you can use here

```
public class myInteger{
   private int innerVal;

   public int getInnerVal(){ return innerVal};

   public void myInteger(int val) { innerVal = val;}

   public void add(myInteger secondInt)
   {
      int sum = innerVal + secondInt.innerVal;

      if(sum > innerVal)
      {
          innerVal = sum;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to prevent an int from being subtracted from?

If the `int` variable is accessible (and not `final`) then No.

The only way to do this kind of thing is to make the variable inaccessible (e.g. `private`) and then provide methods that allow the caller what you want to happen, and forbid the things that you don't want to happen.